# How to write unit test for this class using Junit and mockito?

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermockito

Below is a class I want to write unit test using Junit and Mockito. I am not able to do that.

The interface loads a native library and then the native library methods are called using the class methods. I need to write unit test for these methods by mocking native library methods. I find it tricky as the native methods are called using InterfaceA.INSTANCE.method1(). How do I mock it?

```
package x.x.x;
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Platform;

public class ClassB {
    
    public interface InterfaceA extends Library {
        
        InterfaceA INSTANCE = (InterfaceA) Native.load("ClassA.api", InterfaceA.class);
        int interfaceMethod1();
        int interfaceMethod2(String string1);
    }    

    public boolean method1(){
        int result = InterfaceA.INSTANCE.interfaceMethod1();
        return result != 0;
    }

    public boolean method2(String string1){
        int result = InterfaceA.INSTANCE.interfaceMethod2(string1);
        return result != 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: "I find it tricky as the native methods are called using InterfaceA.INSTANCE.method1()" Yes. Instead of using that, inject an instance of `InterfaceA`, either as a method parameter or a constructor parameter to `ClassB`.

Comment: Thank you! your comment was very useful. It worked